# Подскажите пожалуйста, почему тут NullPointerException?

Tags: android, java

Хотелось бы вынести работу с файлами в отдельный файл fSave.java, подскажите пожалуйста куда копать?

```
//////////////////////////////////////
///////////////fSave//////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.io.*;

public class fSave extends Activity
{

    public void saveF()
    {
        try
        {
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("f.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE));     // NullPointerException Подскажите пожалуйста, почему?
            osw.write("hello");
            osw.close();
        }
        catch(Throwable t)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////MainActivity.java///////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MainActivity extends fSave
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        fSave save = new fSave();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(mainLayout);

        mainLayout.setOrientation(0);
        mainLayout.addView(text);

        try
        {
            /*
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("f.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE)); // это работает
            osw.write("hello!");
            osw.close();
            */
            save.saveF(); // а тоже самое только в методе класса делает NullPointerException

            text.setText("hello!");
        }
        catch(Throwable t)
        {
            text.setText(t.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы решить проблему Вам надо вызвать `this.saveF()`, а не создавать отдельный класс. Вы же от него наследуютесь.

Теперь почему exception - Вы создаёте активити в активити (save), но не инициализируюте его (нет контекста и прочего) - в итоге ошибка.

Comment: Работает, Спасибо!
А не подскажите как вызвать saveF() если не будет наследования, что бы создать экземпляр класса и через него вызывать функцию?

Comment: Не наследуйте его от активити, и разрулите все требуемые параметры?